# fullcalendar - pass in locale variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

How can I pass `I18n.locale` to fullcalendar, so that the calendar language changes if user changes the `I18.locale`?

My js:

```
  return $('#event_calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    events: app.vars.events,
    locale: 'I18n.locale' )}
```

('I18n.locale') does not work and renders default language instead.

Application_controller:

```
I18n.locale = Tenant.current_tenant.try(:locale)  || I18n.default_locale
```

Comment: Could you find a solution for your problem at the end? I have the same issue now, I would have thought it was a common function to have, but struggling to find much resources out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how ruby works and i am absolutely not 100% sure but i think if you pass 'I18n.locale', your're passing the string "I18n.locale" try removing the quotes and also make sure the fullCalendar locales are included in the project like documented [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale)